# Using ng-transclude inside ng-switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having trouble getting ng-transclude to work within an ng-switch-default directive. Here's my code:

**Directive:**

```
.directive('field', ['$compile', function($complile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                type: '@',
            },
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: 'partials/formField.html',
            replace: true
        };
    }])
```

***partials/formField.html***

```
<div ng-switch on="type">
    <input ng-switch-when="text" ng-model="$parent.ngModel" type="text">
    <div ng-switch-default>
        <div ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I call it like so...

```
<field type="other" label="My field">
    test...
 </field>
```

Which produces the error:

```
[ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found.
```

It works without a hitch, outside of the ng-switch directive, I'm at a loss on how to get this working though. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Here's a live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/3CEj5OY8uXMag75Xnliq?p=preview

Comment: Could you post a live demo? It would be easier to test and find a solution.

Comment: @elclanrs Here ya go... http://plnkr.co/edit/3CEj5OY8uXMag75Xnliq?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from: [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4969#issuecomment-38887046)

The problem is that ng-switch is using a transclude as well, which leads to the error.

In this case, you should create a new directive that uses the right $transclude function. For this to work, store the $transclude in the controller of your parent directive (in your case field), and create a new directive that references that controller and uses its $transclude function.

In your example:

```
.directive('field', function() {
  return {
       ....
      controller: ['$transclude', function($transclude) {
        this.$transclude = $transclude;
      }],
      transclude: true,
       ....
  };
})
.directive('fieldTransclude', function() {
  return {
    require: '^field',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, fieldCtrl) {
      fieldCtrl.$transclude(function(clone) {
        $element.empty();
        $element.append(clone);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

In the html, you then just use `<div field-transclude>` instead of `<div ng-transclude>`.

Here is an updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/au6pxVpGZz3vWTUcTCFT?p=preview

Comment: Is the `$transclude` function documented anywhere? I can't find it in the Angular docs.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `ng-switch` is doing its own transclusion.  Because of this, your transclusion is getting lost with the transclusion of `ng-switch`.

I don't think you will be able to use `ng-switch` here.

You can use [`ng-if`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngIf) or [`ng-show`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow) instead:

```
<input ng-if="type == 'text'" ng-model="$parent.ngModel" type="{{type}}" class="form-control" id="{{id}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-required="required">
<div ng-if="type != 'text'">
    <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would appear this is a bug in the current version of the framework. I've logged an issue on Github here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4969 ... Thanks for the workaround, I suppose it will have to do for now!