# Could not get input data from modal pop up using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the modal pop up where my form is present and I am unable to get the form data via `ng-model` using Angular.js. I am providing my code below.

```
<modal title="Owner Information" visible="showModal">
  <form class="ng-pristine ng-valid" id="frmsignup" name="frmsignup"  autocomplete="off">
  <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 plr-15">
        <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-left">Status:</span>
            <select class="form-control" name="status"  id="status" ng-model="status" required="required">
            <option value="">Select Status</option>
            <option value="1">Active</option>
            <option value="0">Inactive</option>
            </select>
  </div>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 plr-15">
        <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-left">Comment:</span>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="50" class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment" ng-model="comment" required="required">
            </textarea>
    </div>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updateOwnerData();" id="addProfileData" value="Save" />
</form>
</modal>
```

My modal pop up is given below.

```
var dept=angular.module('cab');
dept.controller('ownerviewController',function($scope,$http,$timeout,$state,Upload,$window,DataService){
   $scope.updateOwnerData=function(){
          console.log('data',$scope.status,$scope.comment);
   }
})
dept.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

The above is my script part. Here My issue is I could not get value through `$scope` from pop up window. I need to collect the value via Angular.js `Scope`.

Comment: can you add a snippet please

Comment: @AdeshKumar : Did not get you. I have added all required code.

Comment: @satya have you tried with `console.log('data',$scope.$parent)`

Comment: you have added the code but not a working snippet which stackoverflow offers

Comment: @MayankVadiya: Let me to check and update you.

Comment: You have to use the parent scope might be the modal is creating its own scope and not using the parent scope

Comment: @MayankVadiya: No, I tried but same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I failed to figure out what is the problem with scopes. It seems that values are propagated inside (so, you can set the initial value for `ng-model`) but they do not come outside, so I've used `controllerAs` syntax and view model principle:

```
dept.controller('ownerviewController',function($scope){

    var vm = this; // Creating view model

    $scope.openPopUP=function(){
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    }
    $scope.updateOwnerData=function(){
        console.log('data', vm.status, vm.comment); //Showing data from view model
    } 
})
```

Next step, you should define view model in your template by means of `controllerAs` syntax and change ng-model bindings:

```
<body ng-controller="ownerviewController as vm">
...
   <select class="form-control" name="status" id="status" ng-model="vm.status" required="required">
   ...
```

You can find the working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/OnPj4HhJp4xBGyBGwOXu?p=preview)

The full version with modal popup is also [available](https://plnkr.co/edit/zLoELL2T25YvZOXdPMsk?p=preview)

Comment: I chnaged as per you added `$parent.status` but same issue with `$scope.status`.

Comment: That's strange. I think I'll wait for the snippet then

Comment: Ok,let me to add.

Comment: Your plunker example doesn't work at all. I'll come back to your question in a while

Comment: Ok..yes some angular version issue I think.

Comment: @satya, I've updated my answer with a working solution. Feel free to check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188810/discussion-between-sergey-mell-and-satya).

Comment: I like your fiddle. It works just great when I put it into my own code. Just one problem -  the modal dialog is visible at the start. I need it to stay hidden until my code wants to launch it. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

#### scopes

In the *modal pop-up* directive both `transcluded: true` and `scope: true` create their own isolated scope. The scope you want to get the updated inputs is yet another: your controller's scope.

See visual explanation in [Access Parent Scope in Transcluded Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16868935).

#### communication

In order to communicate from inside the directive/transcluded-form with the **parent's scope** you can use the following:

- add an **own scope** `scope: { status: '=', comment: '=' }` to your directive and use two-way-binding `'='` to pass the parent's scope-variables like `<modal title="Owner Information" visible="showModal" data-status="status", data-comment="comment">`
- create and inject a **factory or service** to handle communication (i.e. data-updates) between directive (form) and controller

See [AngularJS : Directive transcluded scope lost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23201824)

#### solution with (inherited) scope

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45ck7yr9/).
It just uses the parent scope (from controller) via prototypical inheritance.
So the model (status, comment) can be used as well as the function to update can be called within the transcluded form.