# ngTransclude in ngSwitch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude, angularjs-ng-switch

I have a popover, and this popover has ngTransclude. We show/set popup with ngSwitch (true/false). The issue here is that ngTransclude is inside ngSwitch and this slows down the application, because every time we show a popover we have to transclude/$compile. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Now we cannot just move transclude outside of popup, because that means, if I have a ng-repeat inside transcluded element, this ng-repeat is watched then, but we dont want that, we want to watch for this ng-repeat when popup is opened.

Comment: showing your code would increase your chances to get a good answer. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20000142/2794702

Comment: it is a complex example, the description explains how and what is the problem.