# How to switch between components that uses ng-transclude?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude, angularjs-components

### Switching Between Components

We have two components, `<hello></hello>` and `<goodbye></goodbye>`. Both components have transclusion, allowing them to be used in manners such as `<hello>World</hello>` or `<goodbye>World</goodbye>`.

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .component('hello', {
    template: '<h1>Hello, <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>!</h1>',
    transclude: true
  })
  .component('goodbye', {
    template: '<h1>Goodbye, <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>!</h1>',
    transclude: true
  });
```

Now, we want the ability to switch between using the `<hello></hello>` component or the `<goodbye></goodbye>`. One way that this can be done is using `ng-if`. [(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/5k3pujh8/)

**script.js**

```
...
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.component = 'hello';
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <hello ng-if="component === 'hello'">World</hello>
    <goodbye ng-if="component === 'goodbye'">World</goodbye>
</div>
```

### Problem With Repeated Code

However, what if our transclusion included significantly more lines? Instead of simply `<hello>World</hello>`, we may have `<hello><!-- Many lines which we'd rather not repeat twice --></hello>`. If we use the same method to do this, we would end up with a lot of repeated code. So it would be nice if we can simply "switch out" components. [(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/5k3pujh8/2/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <hello ng-if="component === 'hello'">
    <goodbye ng-if="component === 'goodbye'">
    Lorem Ipsum.........
    </goodbye>
    </hello>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as intended. Setting `$scope.component = 'hello'` would yield `Hello, !`, and setting `$scope.component = 'goodbye'` would yield a blank page. My interpretation of this behavior is that angularjs is parsing this as `<goodbye></goodbye>` nested within `<hello></hello>`, rather than switching between using `<hello></hello>` or `<goodbye></goodbye>`. The desired behavior is more along the lines of an *if-else if* statement.

I have also tried using `ng-switch on`. [(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/5k3pujh8/3/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <div ng-switch on="component">
    <hello ng-switch-when="hello">
    <goodbye ng-switch-when="goodbye">
    Lorem Ipsum.........
    </goodbye>
    </hello>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, this yields a Multiple Directive Resource Contention error.

> Error: $compile:multidir
>
> Multiple Directive Resource Contention
>
> `Multiple directives [ngSwitchWhen, hello] asking for transclusion on: <hello ng-switch-when="hello">`

### Similar Issue

From the question [Using ng-transclude inside ng-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998934/using-ng-transclude-inside-ng-switch), the [Github Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4969#issuecomment-38887046) claims to have fixed a similar bug. However, the fix only applies when the `ng-transclude` is nested within a `<div></div>` block as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <div ng-switch on="component">
    <div ng-switch-when="hello">
      <hello>Lorem Ipsum.........</hello>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="goodbye">
      <goodbye>Lorem Ipsum.........</goodbye>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this will not solve the issue of repeated code that I described earlier.

### So my question is

Is there a way to switch out components while keeping the transcluded code the same, but without having to rewrite the transcluded code multiple times?

If not, what alternate methods can I use to achieve my goal while keeping the amount of repeated code to a minimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One work around to this problem is to make the `<!-- Many lines which we'd rather not repeat twice -->` into another component. [(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ugyg0gkc/1/)

```
.component('common', {
  template: 'Lorem Ipsum.........'
})
```

Now, the only repeated code would be the tag for the component.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <hello ng-if="component === 'hello'"><common></common></hello>
  <goodbye ng-if="component === 'goodbye'"><common></common></goodbye>
</div>
```

If an additional component is undesirable, it is also possible to do the same with `ng-include`.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <hello ng-if="component === 'hello'"><ng-include src="'common.html'"></ng-include></hello>
  <goodbye ng-if="component === 'goodbye'"><ng-include src="'common.html'"></ng-include></goodbye>
</div>
```